# How to open context menu in mcedit under ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, mc, mcedit, ubuntu-16.04

Can't open context menu with mouse right click. It worked fine in ubuntu 14.04. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as easy as just holding shift key during right click. Well, it was never required before 16.04.